# Covariance of Stochastic Differential Equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, covariance, stochastic-differential-equations

What is the general expression for the covariance $cov \left[ X_s X_t \right]$ of a stochastic process given by
\begin{equation}
dX_t = f(X_t,t)dt + g(X_t,t) dW_t
\end{equation}
for some general (sufficiently well-behaved) functions $f$ and $g$?

Comment: What do you mean by "general expression"? General expression in terms of ... ?

Comment: Formally, the solution to the above is just \begin{equation} X(t) = X_0 + \int_0^t f(X,r) dr + \int_0^t g(X,r) dW_r. \end{equation} for some initial value $X_0$. So now I can just calculate $cov \left[ X(s) X(t) \right]$ by plugging in this formal solution. Of course, I cannot evaluate the integrals but I assume that several of the integrals that will appear in this calculation will drop out due to standard rules from stochastic calculus such as \begin{equation} \mathbb{E} \left[ \int f(X,r) dW_r \right] = 0 \end{equation} and possibly many more.

Comment: Well, yes... so have you tried Itô's formula?

Comment: @ user56643 : You can even use the weaker than ITô's rule, stochastic integration by parts formula (for continuous semimartingale) ? Best regards

Comment: If $X_0=0$, the covariance of $X_s$ and $X_t$ is $$\int_0^{t\wedge s}E(g(X_u,u)^2)du.$$

Comment: Thx Did, that's exactly the kind of result that I was looking for. I assume you obtained this by plugging in the above formal solution (with $X_0 = 0$) into the defintion of the correlation and then using that several of the resulting integrals disappear or simplify. Do you know a source which shows the derivation of this?

Answer (score 2):

Here we simply apply Ito isometry. So as explained [Quadratic Variations and the Ito Isometry](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/03/29/quadratic-variations-and-the-ito-isometry/) we have

$$ EX_{t}X_{r}=E[\int^t b ds\int^r b ds]+E[\int^t b ds \int^r \sigma dB_{s}]+E[\int^r b ds \int^t \sigma dB_{s}]+E[\int^{t} \sigma dB_{s}\int^r \sigma dB_{s}]$$

A good reference for quadratic variation computations is Revuz-Yor chapter IV. For Brownian motion, we know that $d\langle B,t\rangle=0$ is zero because generally the cross-variation of a semimartingale and an increasing process is zero [Quadratic Variation of Increasing Process?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222117/quadratic-variation-of-increasing-process). The quadratic variation for $B_{t}$ is $t$ and so we indeed get by Itô isometry

$$ EX_{t}X_{r}=E[\int^t b ds\int^r b ds]+E[\int^{t} \sigma dB_{s}\int^r \sigma dB_{s}]$$

$$ =E[\int^t b ds\int^r b ds]+\int^{\min(t,r)} E\sigma^{2} ds.$$

Comment: I didn't claim σ  is deterministic. The Itô-isometry is true for some random processes too see Theorem 6 https://almostsuremath.com/2010/03/29/quadratic-variations-and-the-ito-isometry/

Comment: Actually, I have to think about this a bit more. Will delete my answer for now.

Comment: Done. Your answer is totally correct.

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. Temporarily I thought that for non deterministic
integrands it is not possible to deduce from the Ito isometry
$$\tag{1}
\mathbb E\big[\textstyle(\int_0^t\alpha_u\,dW_u)(\int_0^t\beta_u\,dW_u)\big]=
\mathbb E\big[\textstyle\int_0^t\alpha_u\beta_u\,du\big]
$$
that
$$\tag{2}
\mathbb E\big[\textstyle(\int_0^t\alpha_u\,dW_u)(\int_0^\color{red}{s}\beta_u\,dW_u)\big]=
\textstyle\int_0^{t\wedge s}\mathbb E\big[\alpha_u\beta_u\big]\,du
$$
holds. But this is in fact quite simple: The LHS of (2) equals
\begin{align}
&\mathbb E\big[\textstyle(\int_0^t\alpha_u\,dW_u)(\int_0^t\beta_u1_{\{u\le s\}}\,dW_u)\big]\stackrel{(1)}{=}\mathbb E\big[\int_0^t\alpha_u\beta_u1_{\{u\le s\}}\,ds\big]\\[2mm]
&=\textstyle\int_0^t\mathbb E\big[\alpha_u\beta_u\big]1_{\{u\le s\}}\,ds=
\int_0^{t\wedge s}\mathbb E\big[\alpha_u\beta_u\big]\,du\,.\tag{3}
\end{align}