# Grönwall inequality for semimartingales

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm trying to prove the following version of the Grönwall inequality: Suppose that

$0 \leq A_t \leq \alpha + \int_0^t A_{s-}dC_s$

for a non-decreasing cadlag process $C$. Show that

$A_t \leq \alpha e^{C_t}$.

**Proof attempt:**

Inspired by other proofs of the Grönwall inequality, I'm trying to find an upper bound of $\int A_{s-}dC_s$ which does not depend on $A$, by utilizing the change of variables formula and integration by parts in a clever way. For instance, $e^{-C_t}$ satisfies by the change of variables formula (aka Ito formula)

$ e^{-C_t} = e^{-C_0} - \int_{0^+}^t e^{-C_{s-}}dC_s +\sum_{0 < s \leq t} \Big( \Delta e^{-C_s} + e^{-C_{s-}}\Delta C_s \Big).$

This gives, using integration by parts,

$e^{-C_t}\int_{0+}^t A_{s-}dC_s = \int_{0^+}^t e^{-C_{s-}}A_{s-}dC_s + \int_{0+}^t \int_{0+}^{s-} A_{u-}dC_u d(e^{C_s}) + [e^{-C},\int_{0+}^{\cdot} A_{s-}dC_s]_t.$

$= \int_{0^+}^t e^{C_{s-}}(A_{s-} - \int_{0+}^{s-} A_{u-}dC_u)dC_s + \sum_{0<s\leq t} \int_{0+}^{s-}A_{u-}dC_u \Big( \Delta e^{-C_s} + e^{-C_{s-}}\Delta C_s \Big) + [e^{-C},\int_{0+}^{\cdot} A_{s-}dC_s]_t.$

The first term on the rhs is bounded above by $\alpha\int_{0+}^t e^{-C_{s-}}dC_s$ by assumption, and therefore does not depend on $A$. However, I'm struggling to deal with the two other terms.. Any help or hints are greatly appreciated.

**Edit:** We should have $[e^{-C},\int_{0+}^{\cdot} A_{s-}dC_s] \leq 0$, since this is the quadratic covariation between a non-decreasing process and a non-increasing process, which should be non-increasing.

For reference, this is exercise 14, chapter V, p. 358 in Protter - Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is called "Stochastic Gronwall-type inequality" (see Lemma 2.1 "A new proof for comparison theorems for stochastic differential inequalities with respect to semimartingales", whose proof we alter.)

Let $N_t; U_t; B_t$ be one-dimensional processes such that $N$ is a semimartingale and, $B$ is a nondecreasing càdlàg process and for $t\geq s\geq 0$

$$U_{t}\leq N_{t}+\int_{s}^{t}U_{r}dB_{r}.$$

Then

$$U_{t}\leq(N_{s}e^{-B_{s}}+\int_{s}^{t}e^{-B_{r}}dN_{r}) e^{B_{t}}.$$

Proof

By Itô we have

$$N_t e^{-B_{t}}=N_{s}e^{-B_{s}}+\int_{s}^{t}e^{-B_{r}}dN_{r}-\int_{s}^{t}e^{-B_{r}}N_{r}dB_{r}$$

and

$$e^{-B_{t}}\int_{s}^{t}U_{r}dB_{r}=\int_{s}^{t}e^{-B_{r}}U_{r}dB_{r}-\int_{s}^{t}e^{-B_{r}}\left(\int_{s}^{r} U_{w}dB_{w}\right)dB_{r},$$

where the cross-variation term is zero because generally, the cross variation of a continuous semimartingale X and an adapted nonincreasing process Y is zero $[X,Y]=0$ (eg. see [Quadratic Covariation of an Increasing Process with another Process is 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092878/quadratic-covariation-of-an-increasing-process-with-another-process-is-0) where they do it for increasing but the proof is the same since we again get a telescoping sum)

Therefore,

$$U_t e^{-B_{t}}\leq N_{t}e^{-B_{t}}+e^{-B_{t}}\int_{s}^{t}U_{r}dB_{r}$$

$$=N_{s}e^{-B_{s}}+\int_{s}^{t}e^{-B_{r}}dN_{r}+\int_{s}^{t}e^{-B_{r}}\left( U_{r}-N_{r}-\int_{s}^{r} U_{w}dB_{w}\right)dB_{r}$$

the last term is nonpositive

$$\leq N_{s}e^{-B_{s}}+\int_{s}^{t}e^{-B_{r}}dN_{r}.$$

Therefore,

$$U_{t}\leq e^{B_t}\left(N_{s}e^{-B_{s}}+\int_{s}^{t}e^{-B_{r}}dN_{r} \right).$$

If $N_{t}\equiv \alpha$ and $s=0$, we get

$$U_{t}\leq \alpha e^{B_t}.$$

Comment: I appreciate the reply and the provided reference. The thing is that the solution you provided seems to rely on the additional assumption that the processes involved are continuous. Moreover, the bound you provide is different from the bound that I was after..

Comment: @northwiz I agree. I updated.

Comment: I'm not sure about the statement "generally, the cross variation of a semimartingale X and an adapted nonincreasing process Y is zero [X,Y]=0". For instance, if $N$ is a counting process it is (under integrability conditions) a semimartingale with respect to its natural filtration. And $-N$ is adapted and non-increasing. But $[N,-N]$ is generally different from $0$.

Comment: @northwiz I meant to add continuous semimartingale X. See the link i attached for proof. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092878/quadratic-covariation-of-an-increasing-process-with-another-process-is-0